# When calling multi-input model. I'm getting error: Could not compute output KerasTensor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm getting a when trying to incorporate embedding into my GAN error:

```
AssertionError: Could not compute output KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='dense_270/BiasAdd:0', description="created by layer 'dense_270'")
```

I was playing with this code by sending it a straight numpy array. This is the working version without embeddings:

```
# Build Generative model ...
g_input = Input(shape=[Xtrain.shape[1]])
H1 = Dense(512)(g_input)
H1r = Activation('relu')(H1)
H2 = Dense(256)(H1r)
H2r = Activation('relu')(H2)
H3 = Dense(256)(H2r)
H3r = Activation('relu')(H3)
H4 = Dense(128)(H3r)
H4r = Activation('relu')(H4)
H5 = Dense(128)(H4r)

H5r = Activation('relu')(H5)
H6 = Dense(64)(H5r)
H6r = Activation('relu')(H6)
H7 = Dense(32)(H6r)
Hr = Activation('relu')(H7)
g_V = Dense(1)(Hr)

generator = Model(g_input,g_V)
generator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt)
generator.summary()


# Build Discriminative model ...
d_input = Input(shape=[Xtrain.shape[1]+1])
H = Dense(256)(d_input)
H = Activation('relu')(H)
H = Dense(256)(H)
H = Activation('relu')(H)
H = Dense(64)(H)
H = Activation('relu')(H)
H = Dense(32)(H)
H = Activation('relu')(H)
d_V = Dense(2,activation='softmax')(H)
discriminator = Model(d_input,d_V)
discriminator.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=dopt)
discriminator.summary()

# Freeze weights in the discriminator for stacked training
make_trainable(discriminator, False)

# Build stacked GAN model
gan_input = Input(shape=Xtrain.shape[1])
H = generator(gan_input)
gd_input=Concatenate()([gan_input,H])
gan_V = discriminator(gd_input)
GAN = Model(gan_input, [gan_V,H])
GAN.compile(loss=['categorical_crossentropy','mse'], optimizer=opt) #Complete GAN have both loss functions
GAN.summary()
```

Then, I took my original numpy array and added 2 numpy arrays into each row so it's basically a few values then an array. Like this -

```
[32,53, .43, [1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
```

To use this model with that modifications in the data, I made the following changes:

```
# Build Generative model ...
g_input = Input(shape=[len(total_x[0])-2]) #have a array that's only a numpy array by excluding last 2 items)
np_input = Input(shape=[len(total_x[0][:-1])]) #include only the last arrray
mergedLayer = layers.concatenate([g_input, np_input]) #merge both 
H1 = Dense(512)(mergedLayer) #everything after is the same
```

Then I changed the generator to accept two inputs instead of one:

```
generator = Model([g_input,np_input],g_V)
```

But then I get the above error on this part:

```
H = generator(gan_input)
```

I'm new to ML but I thought based on the above, maybe I can pass it a concatenated layer but it didn't work(basically the same logic as above):

```
gan_dataframe_input = Input(shape=[Xtrain.shape[1]-2])
numpy_input = Input(shape=2) 
gan_input = layers.concatenate([gan_dataframe_input, numpy_input])
H = generator(gan_input)
```

I hope this is enough info to help or give me suggestions. Here's the full stack trace if it helps:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-52760dc68480> in <module>()
     54 gan_input = layers.concatenate([gan_dataframe_input, numpy_input])
     55 
---> 56 H = generator(gan_dataframe_input)
     57 gd_input=Concatenate()([gan_input,H])
     58 gan_V = discriminator(gd_input)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    950     if _in_functional_construction_mode(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_list):
    951       return self._functional_construction_call(inputs, args, kwargs,
--> 952                                                 input_list)
    953 
    954     # Maintains info about the `Layer.call` stack.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _functional_construction_call(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_list)
   1089         # Check input assumptions set after layer building, e.g. input shape.
   1090         outputs = self._keras_tensor_symbolic_call(
-> 1091             inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
   1092 
   1093         if outputs is None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call(self, inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
    820       return nest.map_structure(keras_tensor.KerasTensor, output_signature)
    821     else:
--> 822       return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
    823 
    824   def _infer_output_signature(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _infer_output_signature(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
    861           # TODO(kaftan): do we maybe_build here, or have we already done it?
    862           self._maybe_build(inputs)
--> 863           outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    864 
    865         self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, outputs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py in call(self, inputs, training, mask)
    423     """
    424     return self._run_internal_graph(
--> 425         inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    426 
    427   def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py in _run_internal_graph(self, inputs, training, mask)
    567     for x in self.outputs:
    568       x_id = str(id(x))
--> 569       assert x_id in tensor_dict, 'Could not compute output ' + str(x)
    570       output_tensors.append(tensor_dict[x_id].pop())
    571 

AssertionError: Could not compute output KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='dense_270/BiasAdd:0', description="created by layer 'dense_270'")
```

Also if it helps, here's the code above with the modifications I made that's generating this error:

```
# Build Generative model ...
g_input = Input(shape=[len(total_x[0])-2])
np_input = Input(shape=[len(total_x[0][:-1])]) 
mergedLayer = layers.concatenate([g_input, np_input])
H1 = Dense(512)(mergedLayer)
H1r = Activation('relu')(H1)
H2 = Dense(256)(H1r)
H2r = Activation('relu')(H2)
H3 = Dense(256)(H2r)
H3r = Activation('relu')(H3)
H4 = Dense(128)(H3r)
H4r = Activation('relu')(H4)
H5 = Dense(128)(H4r)

H5r = Activation('relu')(H5)
H6 = Dense(64)(H5r)
H6r = Activation('relu')(H6)
H7 = Dense(32)(H6r)
Hr = Activation('relu')(H7)
g_V = Dense(1)(Hr)

generator = Model([g_input,np_input],g_V)
generator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt)
# generator.summary()
# utils.plot_model(generator, show_layer_names=False, show_shapes=True)

# Build Discriminative model ...
d_input = Input(shape=[Xtrain.shape[1]+1])
H = Dense(256)(d_input)
H = Activation('relu')(H)
H = Dense(256)(H)
H = Activation('relu')(H)
H = Dense(64)(H)
H = Activation('relu')(H)
H = Dense(32)(H)
H = Activation('relu')(H)
d_V = Dense(2,activation='softmax')(H)
discriminator = Model(d_input,d_V)
discriminator.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=dopt)
# discriminator.summary()

# Freeze weights in the discriminator for stacked training
make_trainable(discriminator, False)

# Build stacked GAN model
# gan_input = Input(shape=Xtrain.shape[1]) #old

gan_dataframe_input = Input(shape=[Xtrain.shape[1]-2])
numpy_input = Input(shape=2) 
gan_input = layers.concatenate([gan_dataframe_input, numpy_input])

H = generator(gan_input)
gd_input=Concatenate()([gan_input,H])
gan_V = discriminator(gd_input)
GAN = Model(gan_input, [gan_V,H])
GAN.compile(loss=['categorical_crossentropy','mse'], optimizer=opt) #Complete GAN have both loss functions
GAN.summary()
```

Any suggestions or resources to look at would be helpful!

UPDATE - I'm not sure if I'm getting closer or further. I made the following changes(to try to get the shape to match):

```
gan_dataframe_input = Input(shape=[len(total_x[0])-2])
numpy_input = Input(shape=[len(total_x[0][:-1])]) 
gan_input = layers.concatenate([gan_dataframe_input, numpy_input])

H = generator([gan_dataframe_input,numpy_input])
gd_input=Concatenate()([gan_input,H])
gan_V = discriminator(gd_input)
GAN = Model(gan_input, [gan_V,H])
```

but now I get a error on the last line:

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 659), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_230'), name='input_230', description="created by layer 'input_230'") at layer "concatenate_94". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

I'm not sure if I'm getting closer or not, but the weird thing is my xtrain numpy array is (661,) and my numpy array is (77,0) so I'm not sure why when I print(mergedLayer) I get `KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1319), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='concatenate_93/concat:0', description="created by layer 'concatenate_93'")` It seems it doesn't see the columsn and only the rows? I'm not sure if any of this makes sense, I might be confusing myself more trying to understand multi imputs.